# readthedocs and autodoc - how do I "enable virtualenv"?

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-sphinx

I am trying to use the sphinx-autodoc feature with readthedocs, however since there are some imports which are not found I am getting errors. (see my error log http://readthedocs.org/builds/pyramidal/231348/).

The solution appears to be located here: http://read-the-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=virtualenv#my-project-isn-t-building-with-autodoc where I'm told "enable the virtualenv feature". However I'm not sure what this means and searching for virtualenv in the readthedocs documentation doesn't help. I know what virtualenv is but I'm not sure how the application could possibly help with this issue and where the option to enable this virtualenv feature is located.

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 2):

This is many months later, but the virtualenv feature is under your project settings (Project Admin->Edit). You scroll down and check the box for "Use virtualenv"

Comment: I tried this but it actually caused my build to fail. Now I get a 403 forbidden message when I try and access my docs! This is really confusing. Considering its readthedocs the documentation is pretty terrible.

Comment: The best thing I found when my builds were failing (or worse, working, but not building autodoc), was that if you click on any build (HTML or PDF) on the builds panel, it will bring up the output and errors that were generated when sphinx ran. Usually, that can point you in the right direction on what's going on (is it an import error, is it a problem with a directive, etc). Does the output tell you anything interesting? Can you add it to your question?

Comment: Hi Nick, What I'm doing right now is defining a mock class in my conf.py and importing "mock" modules that way. This doesn't work for C modules but that problem was ages ago. I'll write back when I encounter it again though.